# Full duplex PCM bridge

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, audio, alsa, device-tree

I'm working on an embedded device, that runs Linux `4.14.79`, that has 2 hardware PCM, one connected to a bluetooth chip and one to a GSM phone.

My goal is to bridge those streams (`bt-in -> gsm-out` and `gsm-in -> bt-out`) in a fullduplex configuration to handle calls. In fact, the bluetooth is connected to an handset.

My codecs are working, I can use both `aplay` and `arecord` on both cards. I was looking for a solution to bridge those channel together, possibly on the kernel side (for performace). So far I've found:

- [DPCM](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/soc/dpcm.html): tried to edit my DT to use `simple-scu-card` instead of my drivers, but I still end with 2 separated (working) card that wont communicate each other, next step is tweaking my sound drivers.
- `snd-aloop`: from what I've see this wont fit my case: I did not figured out how to bridge my `hw:0,0` with any of `Loopback` card interface.
- `alsaloop`: userspace, however I did not managed to make it works:

```
alsaloop -P hw:1,0 -C hw:0,0 --format S16_LE -c 2 -r 8000 -t 500000
```

The command above results is crackling noise, one frame long, only when I kill the `alsaloop`. I've also tried different period and buffer sizes, nothing changes (expect for xruns with weird values). I will do more tests soon.

Due to the limited resources I'd like to avoid the use of `Jack` and/or `pulseaudio`.

My question is: has anyone faced a problem like mine before and can provide me some resource/document/example?

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

**NB**: I've been in this topic for a couple of weeks now, if this question is lacking information, please let me know.

Comment: Does playback/recording with `aplay`/`arecord` work? Even both at the same time?

Comment: @CL. Yes, doing `arecord -D hw:1,0 -f S16_LE -r 8000 -c 2 | aplay -D hw:0,0 -f S16_LE -r 8000 -c 2` results in an half-duplex communication

Comment: Your `alsaloop` command also is half duplex; you have to tell it to use two jobs.